# Fractional Exponents Confusion

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponentiation

Let a and b be natural numbers (not including zero).
Is  it true that [image] will not equal [image] for all possible solutions? For instance, if a=b the [image] would always give an output of x (assuming you don't start shifting around the b terms around when raising it to the a power). However, if a=b and [image] there will be b possible solutions not always giving an output of x. So if this truly is the case does anyone else find that  the notation of [image] confusing or am I misssing something?

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^a)^{\frac{1}{b}}=(x^\frac{1}{b})^a;a,b\in \mathbb N^+ $$

For $(x^a)^{\frac{1}{b}}$:

$(x^a)^{\frac{1}{b}}=x^{a*\frac{1}{b}}=x^{\frac{a}{b}}$

Also for $(x^\frac{1}{b})^a$:

$(x^{\frac{1}{b}})^a=x^{\frac{1}{b}*a}=x^{\frac{a}{b}}$

When $a=b$ then $(x^a)^{\frac{1}{b}}=x$ regardless of any real number. Same goes to $(x^\frac{1}{b})^a$, it would still equal $x$.

It should not be possible that $(x^a)^{\frac{1}{b}}\not =(x^\frac{1}{b})^a:a,b\in \mathbb N^+ $unless you can prove me wrong.

Comment: If you have ((1^2)^(1/2))=1^(1/2)=1 and also -1 using De Moivre's theorem. If you have ((1)^(1/2))^2=(1 and also -1)^2=1. Therefore, you don't get back x for the first example because there are 2 possible solutions. However, in the next example you get back x for all solutions.

Comment: Here's a good resource <http://www.ck12.org/book/CK-12-Trigonometry-Concepts/section/6.14/>